# Creating Login form on Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a login for my Access db, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code (keep in mind "Preparer" is the name of the table holding username and password info:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    If IsNull(Me.txtLogin) Then

        MsgBox "Please Enter Login", vbInformation, "Need ID"
        Me.txtLogin.SetFocus

    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then

        MsgBox "Please Enter Password",vbInformation, "Need Password"    
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus

    Else

        If ((IsNull(DLookup("Login","Preparer","Login='& Me.txtLogin.Value &'"))) or _
        (IsNull(DLookup("Password","Preparer","Password='& Me.txtPassword.Value &'")))) Then

            MsgBox "Incorrect Login or Password"

        Else

            DoCmd.Close    
            MsgBox "Success"

            DoCmd.OpenForm "Master"

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

The first two parts work so if login or password is blank it gives the correct error message, but whenever I put a login and password, even if they are correct (i.e. they exist in the preparer table) it gives me the "Incorrect Login or Password"

I'm assuming the problem is in the code here:

```
If ((IsNull(DLookup("Login","Preparer","Login='& Me.txtLogin.Value &'"))) or _
    (IsNull(DLookup("Password","Preparer","Password='& Me.txtPassword.Value &'")))) Then

    MsgBox "Incorrect Login or Password"
```

Anyone understand why I can't get to the bottom else statement?

Comment: Even if this were to work, you are not actually checking the password vs. the login value.  You are checking whether the login name exists and whether the password exists, but they don't need to belong to the same user.  Try to debug.print the "DLookup" part of the isnull statements and find out what is being returned.  I'm guessing at least one of them is always returning Null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not comparing the right information. You should be checking if the `Password` entered for that `Username` exists in the table. So your code should be changed to just one single DLookup, as.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.txtLogin) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Login", vbInformation, "Need ID"
        Me.txtLogin.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Password",vbInformation, "Need Password"    
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    Else
        If Nz(DLookup("Password", "Preparer", "Login = '" & Me.txtLogin.Value & "'")), "GarbageEntry") = Me.txtPassword Then
            DoCmd.Close    
            MsgBox "Success"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Master"
        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect Login or Password"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In the above code, you first use the DLookup to retrieve the Password for the username. IF the username matches, a Password will be returned, ELSE a default value of "**GarbageEntry**" is returned. So the Right password (or) GarbageEntry is compared with the actual password entered. If they are the same then you give them access. Else a message.

Hope this helps !

Comment: You are welcome. If you found this useful, please mark it as answered (the green tick) and/or vote up ! Thanks. :)